# ActiveRecord Nested validation while using embedded documents: Mongoid

Tags: ruby, validation, activerecord, mongoid

I am embedding the courselist document into the parent document called curriculum. The courselist belongs to model course.

courselist model:

```
     include Mongoid::Document
  @schema = {
      'type' => 'object',
      'properties' => {
          # 'id'               => { 'type' => 'string' },
          'course_order_id'  => { 'type' => 'integer'}, #Explicit course ID order
          'course_id'        => { 'type' => 'string' }
      }
  }


  @modelName = 'courselist'
  @collectionName = 'courselist'

  field :course_order_id,   type: Integer
  belongs_to :course #Course model 

  embedded_in :curricula, class_name:"Models::Persistence::Curriculum"
```

Curriculum.rb

```
     @schema = {
      'type' => 'object',
      'properties' => {
          'id'                       => { 'type' => 'string' },
          'title'                    => { 'type' => 'string'  },
          'description'              => { 'type' => 'string'  },
          'cover_image_url'          => { 'type' => 'string'  },
          'trailer_url'              => { 'type' => 'string'  },
          'courselist'               => {'type' => 'array'},
          'price'                    => { 'type' => 'float'   },
          'currency_id'              => { 'type' => 'string' },
          'publisher_id'             => { 'type' => 'string' },
          'certification_ids'        => { 'type' => 'array'   },
          'version'                  => { 'type' => 'integer' },
          'status'                   => { 'type' => 'string'}
      }
  }
  @modelName      = 'curricula'
  @collectionName = 'curricula'


  store_in collection: 'curricula'

  field :title,                     type: String
  field :description,               type: String

  embeds_many :courselist
```

The JSON I get when a GET is performed on curricula route:

```
           "id": "552bfae243534fcdd2a20000",
        "courselist": [
            {
                "_id": {
                    "$oid": "552bfae243534fcdd2a30000"
                },
                "course_order_id": 1,
                "course_id": {
                    "$oid": "552bfae143534fcdd2930000"
                }
            },
            {
                "_id": {
                    "$oid": "552bfae243534fcdd2a40000"
                },
                "course_order_id": 2,
                "course_id": {
                    "$oid": "552bfae243534fcdd29f0000"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

My doubts:

1. What is the meaning of the $oid? Is there a way to override it to a key which wont involve the $ as a prefix ?
2. How can I validate on the courseID of all the objects in the course List? Right now I have written this but it doesn't work :(

   ```
   validate :validate_courselist

   def validate_courselist
   if (courselist == nil)
     return
   end
   if (courselist.uniq.length != courselist.length)
     errors.add :base, "Course ids should be unique"
   end
   courselist.each do |course_id|
     if (Models::Persistence::Course.find_by( _id: course_id) == nil) #this is my issue. How can I get the $oid of the course object??
       errors.add :base, "Course id #{course_id} could not be found"
     end
   end
   ```

   end
   Edit1: The above validation is done at the embedded parent's model. Should it be done at the child? Or at the parent? Or does it not matter? 
   Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That `$oid` stuff is just how `BSON::ObjectId` serializes itself to JSON. You can unwrap it yourself or, if you want to keep using `as_json` and `to_json` on your model instances, you can monkey patch `BSON::ObjectId`:

```
module BSON
  class ObjectId 
    def to_json(*) 
      to_s.to_json
    end
    def as_json(*)
      to_s.as_json
    end
  end 
end
```

I monkey patch to avoid having to deal with the `$oid` stuff all the time.

As far as validation goes, I'd let each thing validate the data that is at its level. You have two separate validations:

1. No repeats in a course list.
2. Each course really is a course.

The `Curriculum` would handle the list as a whole:

```
validate :no_duplicates

def no_duplicates
  if(course_list.map(&:course_id).uniq.length != course_list.length)
    #...
  end
end
```

Note that we're looking at the `course_id`s inside the embedded documents to check uniqueness. Each embedded document will gets its own `_id` and that `_id` is what is usually used for comparisons; we don't care about those, we care about unique courses so that's what we look at.

Then your `Courselist` can take care of its own validity:

```
validates_presence_of :course
```

Checking the presence of the `course` will try to pull the course out of MongoDB. You could replace this with a direct existence check if you thought that this was too expensive.